# Google apps date creation from user input

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var d = e.values[1] + " 10:00:00 UTC";
  var start = new Date(d);

  // oncatenating the string as above fails?   

// ... form then sends an email and adds date to a Google Calendar
```

I'm using a Google spreadsheet to store start, end, title value from a Google Form generated from that spreadsheet.  I now want to add those values to a Google Calendar.

Problem is that if I use concatenation to construct the string (so input can accept 4/4/2013) the date fails, "Invalid Date" when I email myself the values.

Maybe this is weird, but the email with the debug also carries a preceding ' as if it is escaping the value or something ...

```
var emailBody = "Booking enquiry was made on " + timestamp +

  "\n\nThe details they entered were as follows: " +

  "\nFrom: " + start +  " vs original date input : " +  e.values[1] + 

   // etc
```

Gives:
Booking enquiry was made on 11/04/2013 17:53:06

The details they entered were as follows:
From: Invalid Date vs original date input : '04/03/2013

See? '04/03/2013

**UPDATE**

The reply of Serge insas worked, but subsequently I discovered the ' appears only when the Google Form is hosted on my localhost dev server.  When the page is put online (containing the iFrame) then the substring removal trick is not needed as no ' is prepended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ' is used in spreadsheet cells to keep values as strings. If it is removed the the spreadsheet would convert it to a date object.

You can easily remove that ' with  a string operator like [substring()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

```
var withoutQuote = e.values[1].substring(1);
```

Comment: Thx, this worked as you explained.  So the thing to appreciate is that   the data from the Form Submit is done AFTER the data is put into the spreadsheet, and then read from it.  This would explain my problem, I'm glad I the lines about the odd ' to my question!