# Google Apps Script on Form Submit Time Formatting Glitch/Fix

Tags: formatting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Background:**

*How:* I suspect that this is a glitch within Google Form (submission process)/Spreadsheet, but may be part of the Date conversion utility of the Spreadsheet interface (and is an intended feature).

When entering a format in a *text box in Google Forms*, there is some sort of communication error between the Form submit and Response Spreadsheet, or pre-processing of the Form's data before it is sent to the spreadsheet. The glitch only seems to happen for data in a text field of the format `##:## TEXT` where `TEXT` contains **no '.' characters**. For example: `4:15 pm` will reproduce the glitch, but `4:15 p.m` and `4:15 p.m.` will not.

*Result:* An *apostrophe* character is added to the beginning of the string when it is put into the Spreadsheet (i.e. `'4:15 pm`) which throws off several sub-systems I have in place that use that time data. Here are two screenshots (sorry for the bad sizing on the second):

[image: G1][image: G2]

I'm 99% certain that the glitch is caused by the `##:` combination.

**Temporary Fix?:** The real question is... how might I go about removing that pesky apostrophe before I start manipulating the time data? I know how to getValue() of a cell/Range. Assume I have the value of a cell in the following manner:

```
var value = myRange.getValue();
// value = '4:15 pm
```

How can I go about processing that value into `4:15 pm`? A simple java function could be

```
value = value.substring(1); // Assuming "value" is a String
```

But in Google App Scripts for *Spreadsheets*, I don't know how I would do that.

**Post-Script:** It is necessary to post-process this data so that I don't have to lecture university faculty in the language department about inputting time format correctly in their forms.

Thanks in advance to those who can help!

Comment: You have received some good workarounds for a bug that I was unaware of. After some searching, I found that the bug has been escalated about a month ago, and I bumped that escalation. It seems that it is a bug that is associated with the "new" Forms. My testing suggests that the leading single quote is populated for times *or* dates that are considered to be valid times or dates when entered directly into a spreadsheet cell. So if you enter 4:30 pm directly into a cell, it is converted to a numerical time value, where 4:30 p.m. is actually not - it is left as a text string.

Comment: So it is definitely a bug (thanks for reporting), but that was my feeble attempt to describe the bug. If the bug didn't exist (as it didn't with the "old" Forms), you would find your 4:30 p.m. entries would remain as text strings in the spreadsheet, and your 4:30 pm entries would be auto-converted to numerical time values.

Comment: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/docs/forms$20times$20apostrophe/docs/lgsFQccOeqE/Wrc1jZWb5RkJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I go about processing that value into 4:15 pm? A simple java
>   function could be
>
> value = value.substring(1); // Assuming "value" is a String But in
>   Google App Scripts for Spreadsheets, I don't know how I would do that.

Google Apps Scripts uses Javascript which has the exact same method.

```
value = value.substring(1);
```

should return all except the first character.

More about Javascript substring at: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Comment: @Serge insas I don't know anything about JavaScript, but I remember reading about how GAS uses it. So I've got the loop set up to remove any apostrophes from the start of the string in a given cell and can output the result correctly. `'10:00 pm` turns into `10:00 pm`, so that's good. And I have my *project trigger* set up to run the GAS `onFormSubmit`, which is also fine. The only trouble I'm having now is setting the values back into the cell after the apostrophes are removed. I just need to look more into it, but it seems everything except that is working fine now, thanks :)

Comment: great ! (just mention you commented on the wrong person (façon de parler - way of speaking :-) this is Michael's post .)

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the ' in the spreadsheet cell the spreadsheet interface will convert this entry to a date object.

This might (or not) be an issue for you so maybe you should handle this when you read back your data for another use...
It doesn't happen when text is different (for example with P.M) simply because in this case the ' is not necessary for the spreadsheet to keep it as a string since the spreadsheet can't convert it to a date object (time value).

Artificial intelligence has its bad sides ;-)

---

**edit :**
You cant do this in an `onFormSubmit` triggered function using the javascript `substring()` you mentioned. If you're not familiar with that, here is the way to go :

To run a script when a particular action is performed:

1. Open or a create a new Spreadsheet.
2. Click the Unsaved Spreadsheet dialog box and change the name.
3. Choose Tools > Script Editor and write the function you want to run.
4. Choose Resources > Current project's triggers. You see a panel with
   the message No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.
5. Click the link.
6. Under Run, select the function you want executed by the trigger.
7. Under Events, select From Spreadsheet.
8. From the next drop-down list, select On open, On edit, or On form
   submit.
9. Click Save.

see doc [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#ActionTriggers) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events)

Comment: I actually @-ed both of you, but put the text under his answer because his is the one I am going to accept (for confirming my subconscious knowledge that GAS uses JS). I wish I could give you the rep for your response as well, because that bit of knowledge is useful, but I can't accept more than one answer unfortunately =/

Comment: No worries, Michael and I are both GAS Top Contributors, there can't be any concurrency between us :-)  And I like it quite well when multiple answers go in the same (right) direction...

Comment: Yes, I agree completely. I will likely be having more and more questions about GAS the further I get to re-organizing our university faculty communication format with the lab assistants in the language lab. This summer I'll probably be converting 90% of our forms to Google Forms, Spreadsheets and GAS, maybe a Google Site as well to host it all. But I much appreciate the help, I'm completely new to GAS and Drive and stuff in general, learning my way through it as my boss directs the "I want to do this like this" sort of stuff... :)

Comment: Also, I wish that I have seen your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953912/google-apps-date-creation-from-user-input/15957990#15957990), because that answered my apostrophe question... the SO search bar can't reveal **all** the answers I guess... haha :P

Comment: As I said:  artificial intelligence has its limitations and drawbacks :-)

Comment: I am glad my rifle shot hit the target and I am sure Serge's more comprehensive response will help you build a better foundation for future endeavors.