# How to detect if a cell value start with an apostrophe in new Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Assume that in a Google Sheets spreadsheet there is a fill in the blank question in cell A2:

> I ____ happy.

The answer should be written in cell B2. The correct answers are

- 'm
- am

Examples of wrong answers:

- m
- a
- is
- are
- be

The test formula in C2 is `=REGEXMATCH(B2;"^['a]m$")`.

The problem is that when B2 value is `'m` the above formula returns `FALSE` instead of `TRUE`.

By the other hand, by using a Google Apps Script function to check the cell value, getValue() returns `m` instead of `'m`.

```
function check(){
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = file.getSheetByName('Hoja 1');
  var range = sheet.getRange('B2');
  var value = range.getValue();
  throw value;  
}
```

---

UPDATE:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15992619/1595451 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16698417/1595451 are answers for questions relaed to the opposite problem, removing the leading apostrophes. They use `substring(1)` to remove the apostrophes. At this time, when the value is `'m` it return an empty string (`""`).

---

Attribution: The original question was posted in the Google Drive Help forum in Spanish by Salvador Pérez Gómez. [Reconocer expresiones que comienzan por apóstrofe o comilla simple ( ' )](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs-es/sVg3PO8EkTk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel and Google Sheets look for a leading apostrophe to define for formatting, so it's ignored. So, using your `REGEXMATCH` formula, it evaluates to `false` because it skips the apostrophe.

Have the users use two single apostrophes in their response - one to be read as formatting, the other to be read as an apostrophe in English. The regex will return `true.`

Comment: +1. 1) That is how it's working the New Google Sheets, but the old work differently. 2) I'm wondering it this is a feature or a bug. I updated the question. 3) BTW having users (in this case English students) to input double single apostrophes is not a way that I would like to take as this could confuse them.